# has-many through uniqueness of a field based on a field in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Post  
  has_many :post_categories  
  has_many :categories, :through => :post_categories
end

class PostCategory
 belongs_to :post  
 belongs_to :category
end  

class Category
 has_many :post_categories
 has_many :posts, :through => :post_categories
end
```

This is a has_many through relationship wherein post_categories is the join table.

There is field called :title in Post Model. I need to make sure that all titles in a post are unique for a given category. How would I perform the validation based on the category_id in the join table?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, have not tried it though.

validate :unique_title

```
def unique_title
  if self.new_record?
    self.errors.add(:title, "is taken") if self.category.posts.where(:title => self.title).exists?
  else
    self.errors.add(:title, "is taken") if self.category.posts.where("title = '#{self.title}' and id NOT IN (#{self.id})").exists?
  end
end
```